# My external hard drive doesn't show up for boot loader installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, external-hdd, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my external hard drive, but in the partition phase my drive doesn't show up. I am using an s-link brand USB port. The model of it is SW-U517-Type-C Multi-port Adapter. Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS is the version I am trying to install. Does anybody know what should I do?

[image: Installer]

Comment: Welcome! How is your external HD connected? A USB port? What type and model is it? Please edit your question and add this information. Also: what version are you trying to install?

Comment: While in the installer, are you able to open a terminal using Ctrl+Alt+F2? If so, please do so and log into the system using the 'ubuntu' username and perform the command `lsblk`. Are you able to see your connected device in the list? Use  Ctrl+Alt+F1 to return to the installer screen.

Comment: When I open the OS, there are two options: "try ubuntu" and "install ubuntu". I can install ubuntu from "try ubuntu" in the desktop. I can open terminal in "try ubuntu", but how do I log in to the system with ubuntu username?

Comment: Ah I see you've edited your question, and as suspected you're using a type-C port. Ubuntu (and generally Linux kernels) still don't have full driver support for USB-C ports regarding OS boot and install. Maybe this would help: [Cannot boot thumb drive on MBP 2017 to install Linux](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290270/cannot-boot-thumb-drive-on-mbp-2017-to-install-linux)  and [How can I install Ubuntu on a separate partition on my Mac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251380411).

Comment: Yes I can see I guess. sda as the “parent” sda1 sda2 sda3 as “children”

Comment: My A1632 usb adapter from apple didn’t work either. What kind of adapter should I get? I just dont want to involve my mac into this by partitioning it (it can be risky, I dont know much about these things:D)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no answer for that and it is this kind of things that may differ from one device to another. I had a different Issue two years ago trying to make a bootable live OS on a USB-3 flash drive connected to a USB-3 port (non-mac machine), and not all flash drives had a full driver support for this. What I found out was a n online list users created listing what flash drives worked or did not work for them. The other solution was to use a USB-2 port or device. I guess you'll have to dig for an answer or wait for a drivers update to be made..

Comment: Thank you for help. Partition didn't work because of the same reason. Now I am using VM to save the day, but I will figure out a way to use ubuntu from my external hard drive